# Identification of a moth

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

It is from Bangladesh. Is it hawk moth? I am not sure. Please help.

Comment: Looks like a small Sukhoi plane :P. Jokes apart, this doesn't look like a hawk moth. I know that this moth is from Bangladesh since you mentioned that in other posts but it better to always keep your question complete with all necessary information.

Comment: Do you have think this picture is enough for visually identify it (at least at genus level)? Otherwise I gotta hunt this guy :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a [Hesperiidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skipper_%28butterfly%29) (Skipper), not a hawk moth (Sphingidae). There are more than 3500 species of skippers worldwide though, and I don't know what species this is. However, I'm sure that somebody who knows butterflies in Bangladesh could identify this to the genus level.

One suggestion/guess/starting point might be [*Baoris pagana*](http://www.ifoundbutterflies.org/sp/2932/Baoris-pagana), but this is merely based on a quick glance at skippers found in India.

[image]
(picture from http://www.ifoundbutterflies.org/)